# Передача string_view по ссылке или значению

Tags: c++, строки

Как правильно передавать `std::string_view` в функцию, если не надо изменять строку?

Так

```
void foo(std::string_view);
```

или так

```
void foo(const std::string_view&);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос по сути своей родственен массе аналогичных вопросов по поводу других "легковесных" нетривиальных типов. Как лучше передавать `std::initializer_list`? `std::function`? Итераторы контейнеров?

Я бы сказал, что в тех ситуациях, когда у вас есть выбор (то есть вам не нужна копия объекта внутри функции), этот выбор является вопросом персональных предпочтений. Эти объекты действительно легковесны и какие-либо потери производительности при "неоправданной" передаче по значению вы скорее всего не заметите.

Я лично для класс-типов по старинке придерживаюсь правила "если есть сомнения - передавай по константной ссылке", хотя во многих ситуациях в современном С++ это правило уже себя изжило и может быть даже вредным.

Comment: Ну про `std::function` говорят, что надо передавать по значению. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365532/should-i-pass-an-stdfunction-by-const-reference. Аналогичного вопроса/ответа по `std::string_view` не нашёл

Comment: @lycium: Нет, ответ по вашей ссылке говорит об очень специфической ситуации: **если вы и в любом случае собираетесь делать копию передаваемого значения (воможно, тяжелого)**, то лучше пусть ее сделает для вас компилятор - передавайте по значению. Это - хорошее правило. Но мы же здесь говорим о совсем другой ситуации, когда никакой копии делать не нужно. Это совсем другое дело и рассуждения по вашей ссылке к этому никакого отношения не имеют.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: По значению.

---

#### С точки зрения удобства написания кода.

Если у `string_view` надо вызывать методы типа `remove_prefix`/`remove_suffix`, то её надо передавать по значению, т.к. иначе придется делать не-константную копию.

```
void foo(std::string_view);         

void bar(std::string_view view) {     |  void bar(const std::string_view& view) {
  if (view.starts_with("http:")) {    |    auto copy = view;
    view.remove_prefix(5);            |    if (view.starts_with("http:")) { 
  }                                   |      copy.remove_prefix(5);  
  foo(view);                          |    }
}                                     |    foo(view);
                                      |  }
```

#### С точки зрения оптимальности.

В случае если функция будет заинлайнена, то конечно же не будет никакой разницы, т.к. компилятор уберет ссылку. Однако, в общем случае функция не будет заинлайнена, и тогда:

- По значению быстрее потому что не будет лишней индирекции при доступе к содержимому `string_view`.
- Однако при передаче по значению компилятору может понадобиться сделать копию

```
    void bar(std::string_view view) {
      foo(view);
      view.remove_prefix(5);
      foo(view);
    }
```

т.к. вызов функции `foo` может испортить регистры с аргументами (rsi и rdi), то компилятор копирует `view` в другие регистры (rbx и rbp).

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rdi
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rsi
    sub     rsp, 8
    call    foo(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)
    add     rsp, 8
    lea     rdi, [rbp-5]
    lea     rsi, [rbx+5]
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    jmp     foo(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)
```

- При передаче во ссылке может случиться пессимизация из-за алиасинга

```
    size_t n1, n2;
    void some();

    void bar(const std::string_view& view) {
      n1 = view.size();
      some();
      n2 = view.size();
    }
```

т.к. вызов `some()` может поменять значение `view`, то компилятор два раза возьмет `size()` из `view` (при этом он скопирует аргумент из rdi в rbx).

```
    push    rbx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
    mov     rbx, rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR n1[rip], rax
    call    some()
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
    pop     rbx
    mov     QWORD PTR n2[rip], rax
    ret
```

Для сравнения, передача по-значению:

```
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR n1[rip], rdi
    call    some()
    mov     QWORD PTR n2[rip], rbx
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

---

**Вывод:** для `string_view`, `const &` - это лишнее. Не надо тратить время на написание этих букв.

Comment: А что за starts_with? Я не могу найти в интерфейсе такого метода. Вроде он  именуется как     _Starts_with...